# Dynamic subdomain htaccess redirection to dynamic domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to create htaccess rule to redirect all www. subdomains to non-www dynamically, without to enter the domain name. Htaccess is used on parking script where are parked hundreds of domains. So, for example www.site.com must redirect automatically to site.com, www.EveryNextSite.com must redirect automatically to EveryNextSite.com.

I have try many htaccess rules without success, especially for UK domains like co.uk and others, return not expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some attempts and mistakes, I done this with simple regex:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Works also with co.uk, co.za and similar domain names.

Comment: Great. If you'd like to maintain the original protocol, simply remove "http:".